# SSH and DNS and static versus dynamic addressing

Tags: dns

I am trying to grasp the purpose of static versus dynamic addressing, specifically when applied to private network. 
I am using SSH to connect from my PC to RPi via Ethernet.

The RPi has static IP which I simply type as parameter to ssh
like this:

```
os64@os64-desktop:~$ ssh pi@10.0.1.38
```

I have not figured out how to use DNS to name this connection.
I do not see any such configuration in raspi-config to associate DNS with SSH.

How can this be accomplished with commands - using SSH as test  bed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your local network you won't necessarily need to use DNS to access the Pi via a different host name. The `.local` domain, has been officially reserved as a Special-Use Domain Name (SUDN) specifically for the purpose of internal network usage. This way your custom local names don't conflict with existing external addresses.

This will require a service discovery process running on a local network via the mDNS/DNS-SD protocol suite. This could quite possibly already be running on your home router. If not you can install Apple's popular 'Bonjour' local network discovery service either on a Mac or on a [windows machine](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL999). Of course you could always install it on the Pi as '[Avahi](http://www.avahi.org/)' using `sudo apt-get install avahi-daemon`

However, lets assume that there is a mDNS service already running, so straight out of the box the Pi should be able to be accessed using the host name `raspberrypi`. Because it is on your local network you would use `raspberrypi.local`

Therefore from your PC you would access it using;

```
ssh pi@raspberrypi.local
```

To change the host name for the Pi you can either edit `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname` using sudo and nano, changing 'raspberrypi' for a name of your choice (then reboot for it to take effect);

```
sudo nano /etc/hostname
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

... or you can do it via `sudo raspi-config` where you first select 'Network options' and then 'Hostname'.

Comment: Thanks. 

127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters

127.0.1.1       pi

Answer (score 1):

Posted here because it would not fit in as comment

Thanks for very comprehensive reply. 
Since I already had “host” name “pi” assigned in `raspi-config` 
it was just a matter of me using wrong syntax.

```
os64@os64-desktop:~$ ssh pi@pi.local

The authenticity of host 'pi.local (10.0.1.38)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:2hEjoJUeySW/Qqo3d+eV0DEAMX6Ob+9s8W/78/wG2jM.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? Yes 
Warning: Permanently added 'pi.local' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
pi@pi.local's password:
```

And this is my current contents of  `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters

127.0.1.1       pi
```